# Copy and Paste tables from Excel to Outlook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to copy and paste various tables from Excel to Outlook with VBA.

```
Sub GenerateEmail()
    ' Open Outlook
    Dim oOutlook As Object
    Set oOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    ' Open Email
    Dim oEmail As Object
    Set oEmail = oOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    ' Specify the sheet names where the tables are located
    Dim sheetName1 As String
    sheetName1 = "Dashboard" ' Replace "Sheet1" with the name of the first sheet
    
    
    With oEmail
        .To = "Test@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Today"
        .Body = "Thanks"
        .Display
    
        Dim oOutlookInspect As outlook.Inspector
        Dim oWordDoc As Word.Document
        Dim oWordDoc1 As Word.Document
        
        ' 1st Table from sheetName1
        Set oOutlookInspect = .GetInspector
        Set oWordDoc1 = oOutlookInspect.WordEditor
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName1).Range("Table1").Copy
        
        Set oWordRng1 = oWordDoc1.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
        oWordRng1.InsertAfter " " & vbNewLine
        oWordRng1.Collapse Direction:=wCollapseEnd
        oWordRng1.Paste

        
        ' 2nd table from sheetName1 (assuming the table is named "Table2")
        Set oOutlookInspect = .GetInspector ' Get a new Inspector object for the second table
        Set oWordDoc1 = oOutlookInspect.WordEditor ' Use the same Word Document for the second table
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName1).Range("Table2").Copy
        
        Set oWordRng2 = oWordDoc1.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
        oWordRng2.InsertAfter " " & vbNewLine
        oWordRng2.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        oWordRng2.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
        oWordRng2.InsertParagraphAfter
        
         ' 3rd table from sheetName1 (assuming the table is named "Table3")
        Set oOutlookInspect = .GetInspector ' Get a new Inspector object for the second table
        Set oWordDoc1 = oOutlookInspect.WordEditor ' Use the same Word Document for the second table
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName1).Range("Table3").Copy
        
        Set oWordRng3 = oWordDoc1.Application.ActiveDocument.Content
        oWordRng3.InsertAfter " " & vbNewLine
        oWordRng3.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        oWordRng3.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture
        oWordRng3.InsertParagraphAfter
        
        ' Display the email
        '.Display

        ' Clear the objects
        Set oEmail = Nothing
        Set oOutlook = Nothing
    End With
End Sub
```

The first table is correctly pasting as a table (as intended) but the 2nd and 3rd need to be pasted as images. The 2nd and 3rd tables are large and when pasted, I get the error 'image needs to be truncated'. I am just trying to replicate the copy -> paste -> picture pathway which pastes the image in good quality. The 2nd and 3rd images are also pasting on top of eachother-- I need a paragraph space in between each.